# How to update python to latest version and set as default

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-install

I am currently on ubuntu 18.04.

My default python version is Python 3.7.9

I wanted to upgrade it to Python 3.9.2  and set it as default python version

How do I do that ?

Comment: if you don't have it in `apt` then you can add special repo for Ubuntu [deadsnakes Python repo for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) . And after adding repo you should have all versions in `apt`

Comment: You can install pyenv, then manage Python installations from that

Answer (score 3):

Install Python normally with the [deadsnake PPA](https://github.com/deadsnakes):

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.9
```

Check if you can access Python:

```sh
python3.9 --version
```

If so, create a symlink to set it as "default":

```sh
sudo mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.7
sudo ln -s $(which python3.9) /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: `sudo apt install python3.9` this doesn't work

Comment: This is the error I am getting
```E: Unable to locate package python3.9
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.9'
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update`? If so, maybe it's just not available for 18.04.

Comment: Yeah I have done ```sudo apt update```. Still the same

Comment: But this doesn't change the default python 
When I run ```python --version``` its still showing 3.7.9

Comment: Check `which python` and see where is your `python` executable, then update the linking part.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have it in `apt` then you can add special repo [deadsnakes Python repo for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).
And after adding repo you should have all versions in `apt` form `2.3` to `3.10`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install python3.9
```

And later you can find path to actuall version

```
which python
```

and replace is with `python3.9` which you can also find with

```
which python3.9
```

But sometimes it is not good idea to replace it because system may need older version and it will not work with newer one. I prefer to use `python3.9` when I need `3.9` and `python3.7` when I really need `3.7`.

---

After adding this repo it will also inform you when there will be newer version `3.9.x`

---

This repo works also in Linux Mint which is based on Ubuntu.